# Avoid CS8618 I was not able to

Tags: c#

Can you help me?

There is an error made in the code below.

```
using System;

namespace DigitalInovationOne
{
    public class Pilha
    {        
        Posicao primeiro;

        public void Empilha(object item)
        {
            primeiro = new Posicao(primeiro, item);
```

Error CS8618 in posicao primeiro

Comment: That code isn't C — is it C#, for which the tag is [tag:c#]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You should probably include the complete error message verbatim, and the exact source code that triggers it — creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and look at your code. The first thing you do is declare a private field:

```
Posicao primeiro;
```

Notice how you never initialize it/give it a value (this is important).

Then later in your `Empilha()` method you *try* to give it a value:

```
primeiro = new Posicao(primeiro, item);
```

The problem is you are passing the `primeiro` variable in the constructor paramaters, which is still **not initialized with a value**, resulting in the compiler warning CS8618.